# Centroid of the Region bounded by the functions: $y = x, x = \frac{64}{y^2}$, and $y = 8$.

Tags: calculus, curves, centroid

Can someone help and teach me how to solve this problem?

> Find the centroid of the region bounded by the graphs of $$\begin{align} 
> &y = x\\
> &x = \frac{64}{y^2}\\  
> &y = 8 
> \end{align}$$

I'm having trouble solving this problem, please help. Thank you!

I currently don't know how to solve this problem, if someone would show a step-by-step solution would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: How are you getting a solid? I just see a bound area. You say revolution in the title but there is no mention of it in the question. Also you have not shown what you have attempted and where you got stuck.

Comment: Treat $x$ as a function of $y$ instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We can find the $x$ and $y$ coordianates of the centroid separately. There are several formulae that we can use:
$$\sum m_i x_i=\bar x\sum m_i$$
$$\sum m_i y_i=\bar y\sum m_i$$
$$\bar x=\frac{\int_a^bxy ~dx}{\int_a^b y ~dx}$$
$$\bar y=\frac{\int_a^b\frac{1}{2}y^2dx}{\int_a^b y ~dx}$$
If that doesn't help, or if you have any questions, I will be happy to elaborate.